# How to check the size of a contract in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I want to measure the size of my compiled contract using `solc`.

I can dump the binary using `--bin` or `--bin-runtime` and then count how many hexadecimal digits it contains.

Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 20):

### Foundry

You can get a report of the contract byte sizes by adding the `--sizes` flag when building the contracts:

```sh
forge build --sizes
```

### Hardhat

There is this plugin called [hardhat-contract-sizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-contract-sizer):

```sh
$ yarn add --dev hardhat-contract-sizer
```

You load it in the Hardhat config file:

```js
require('hardhat-contract-sizer');
// OR
import "hardhat-contract-sizer";
```

And then you run it:

```sh
$ yarn hardhat size-contracts
```

Comment: Is possible to install in Remix web?

Comment: @JTConsulta no, you can't use Hardhat in Remix. Check out my [template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) for an easy way to bootstrap a Hardhat template.

Answer (score 5):

This approach takes more leg-work, but works:

1. Open your compiled ABI (`build/contracts/YourContract.json`) and grab the value in `deployedBytecode`.  It'll be easier if you use an editor (like Sublime) that lets you collapse JSON values, that you way don't need to scroll past the `abi` value.
2. Copy+paste that value into a new file, save it with a hex extension (e.g. `bytecode.hex`).
3. From your terminal, run `ls -l bytecode.hex` to get the detailed file info which includes the size in bytes.

EDIT: Just saw the detail that you're already dumping the binary from `solc`.  You can always copy-paste that into a file.  Real time-saver here is using `ls -l` rather than counting characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this kosher, but:

(1) I'm using truffle (so built-in solc)

(2) I wrote a script to compute sizes from compiled contracts.  It's pretty trivial.  Not sure if it's accurate, but hey, it seems to do a good job of helping me predict when my contracts aren't gonna deploy.

```
var fs = require('fs') ;

module.exports = async function(cb) {

    const LIMIT = 1*1024 ;

function sizes (name) {
var abi = artifacts.require(name) ;
var size = (abi.bytecode.length / 2) - 1 ;
var deployedSize = (abi.deployedBytecode.length / 2) - 1 ;
return {name, size, deployedSize} ;
}

function fmt(obj) {
return `${ obj.name } ${ obj.size } ${ obj.deployedSize }` ;
}

var l = fs.readdirSync("build/contracts") ;
l.forEach(function (f) {
var name = f.replace(/.json/, '') ;
var sz = sizes(name) ;
if (sz.size >= LIMIT || sz.deployedSize >= LIMIT) {
    console.log(fmt(sz)) ;
}
}) ;
```

}

Comment: how to run this? Create an new file named like `4_check_bytecode.js`, then run`truffle migrate`?

Comment: It's been nearly a year, so I've forgotten details.  Also, a while after this I gave up on truffle and switched to straight JS.  In any case, I think I put this code in a file in scripts/ and used "truffle run ..." to run it.

Comment: yeah, me too and it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it through smart-contracts on-chain check out the `extcodesize` opcode that is available when using solidity assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq` to filter the ABI JSON and then `wc` to count the number of bytes for deployed bytecode:

```
$ cat artifacts/Greeter.json | jq -r '.deployedBytecode' | wc -c
1555
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get contract size in hardhat

*e.g. test.js in /scripts of hardhat project*

```
const hre = require("hardhat")

async function test() {
    // Use Hardhats provider (locally) or your own provider
    const provider = ethers.provider
        
    const bytecode = await provider.getCode(contractAddress)
    const size = bytecode.length / 2
}
```

Comment: Please, don't copy & paste the same answer in multiple questions. If the questions are duplicates please flag them.