# how to figure out the size of the bytecode from compiler output?

Tags: contract-development, evm

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the size of the bytecode given the string, given that there is a hard limit for contract size of 24kb.

ie. for USDT Token:
https://etherscan.io/token/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code

```
606060405260008060146101000a81548160ff021916908315150217
9055506000600355600060045534156200003457600080fd5b604051
62002d7c38038062002d7c8339810160405280805190602001909190
80518201919060200180518201919060200180519060200190919050
50336000806101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffffffff021916908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
ffffff16021790555083600181905550826007908051906020019062
0000cf9291906200017a565b508160089080519060200190620000e8
9291906200017a565b508060098190555083600260008....
```

Is it literally `byte[] all = new byte[s.length() / 2]` - number of characters in the string divided by 2? or it is something more complicated?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the size of a contract in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31515/how-to-check-the-size-of-a-contract-in-solidity)

Comment: no. I'm asking about the actual string of the bytecode already deployed.

Comment: More details about the limit https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/47556/. And you are correct the contract will be deployed as raw bytes, so the deployed size will be hexadecimal lengths / 2. Also be aware that the compiler produces two bytecodes, the runtime and the deployment = runtime + constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this resource on how to figure out the size of the bytecode from compiler output.

See:

[How to check the size of a contract in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31515/how-to-check-the-size-of-a-contract-in-solidity)

[How to estimate my contract code size? it is too big to deploy now](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48534/how-to-estimate-my-contract-code-size-it-is-too-big-to-deploy-now)

Comment: I'm looking at a simpler solution if the hex string is already available.