# I can't deploy contract on eth mainnet

Tags: remix, contract-deployment

**I have deployed this code on many different chains with success except for ETH mainnet and Sepolia.
return error: Transaction mined but execution failed**

https://github.com/lamxoan92/ct/blob/main/a.sol

Comment: This might be increasing the size limit, you can use hardhat contract sizer, to check if it is more than 24kb, if yes you would need to optimize it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the size of a contract in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31515/how-to-check-the-size-of-a-contract-in-solidity)

Comment: Do you have a failed transaction hash?